# Convert Pdf to XML using matlab

Tags: xml, pdf, matlab

how to convert pdf to xml using a matlab script.

this task is easy by iText 5.6 in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab has pretty good interoperability with Java. You should be able call iText's methods from Matlab. More details can be found at [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html).

Comment: It'll work. I've been using iText in a Matlab project for a couple years now.